# How to convert json object into string in Android

Tags: android, json

My JSON format is:

```
[
    {
        "change": 1.59,
        "name": "ABC",
        "price": 10.52,
        "volume": 230
    },
    {
        "change": -0.05,
        "name": "DEF",
        "price": 1.06,
        "volume": 1040
    },
    {
        "change": 0.01,
        "name": "GHI",
        "price": 37.17,
        "volume": 542
    }
]
```

I want to parse it and convert it into string. I am using this method for converting it:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++)
{                                              
    String change = jsonObj.getString(TAG_CHANGE);
    String name = jsonObj.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String price = jsonObj.getString(TAG_PRICE);
    String volume = jsonObj.getString(TAG_VOLUME);
    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    contact.put(TAG_CHANGE, change);
    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
    contact.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
    contact.put(TAG_VOLUME, volume);

    // adding contact to contact list
    contactList.add(contact);
}
```

But I get an error:

> /System.err(867): at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it, It should work

```
JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
    String change = c.getString(TAG_CHANGE);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
    String volume = c.getString(TAG_VOLUME);
    HashMap < String, String > contact = new HashMap < String, String > ();
    contact.put(TAG_CHANGE, change);
    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
    contact.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
    contact.put(TAG_VOLUME, volume);
    contactList.add(contact);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You are getting response as `JSONArray` but you are doing it as `JSONObject`

```
[                // this is JSONArray
      {          // this is JSONObject
```

Change this

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

to

```
JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing in wrong way. your json is starts with an array containing `JsonObjects`. This can be identified since square braces denote `JsonArray` while curly braces denote `JsonObject`. Start with:

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

then iterate through each object, get `JsonObject` at each index and use `getString` method for each key to get values.